# How to implement search functionality in swift 3.1.1?

Tags: swift3, uisearchbar

I want to implement search functionality in my app.
I want to display the search result in tableview.
Below is my code in which I've displayed the names only. And now I want to search image, address, city, mobile number, email and rating.
Thanks in advance!!

searchActive is a bool value set to false, and nameArr and filteredName are string arrays.

```
enter code here
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
    {
        filteredName = self.nameArr.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
            let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })

        if(filteredName.count == 0)
        {
            searchActive = false;
        }

        else
        {
            searchActive = true;
            print("Search Array = \(filteredName)")
        }

        self.infoTableView.reloadData()
    }
```